# Sum up values in multidimensional array in c++ and store it in another multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, xcode6

I try to sum up the values in an array, and would like to store it in another array.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    int rev[2][12] = {{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120},
                        {100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200}};
    
    int temp = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j<2;j++){
        for(int i = 0; i<12; i++){
            temp += rev[j][i];
        }
        cout << "rev in year " << j+1 << ": " << temp << "\n";
        temp = 0;
    }
    
    int revYear[2][1];
    for (int j = 0; j<2;j++){
        for(int i = 0; i<12; i++){
            revYear[j][0] += rev[j][i];
        }
    }
    cout << "rev in year 1: " << revYear[0][0] << "\n";
    cout << "rev in year 2: " << revYear[1][0] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The first two `for` loops give me the desired output I'd like to store in `revYear`, which I tried in the second step. But it returns:

```
rev in year 18363800
rev in year 278010
```

Can anyone help me with this? Is it a compiler issue?

I´m using Mac and Xcode but I also ran the code with MS VS on Windows. Same problem, different output.

Please note: in the upper part, i just wanted to show that I found a way to get the desired output.

Comment: No it is not a compiler issue. It is never a compiler issue. It is you.

Comment: Please note that `revYear` is uninitialized. It also doesn't need to be a 2D array, but that's another story.

Comment: After `temp = 0;` (in the 1st nested loop); `temp` is not use until the last 2 `cout` lines.  This looks strange.

Comment: You might want to put some spaces in your final output so you can actually see the individual values, eg: `cout << "rev in year 1: " << revYear[0][0] << " " << temp << "\n"; cout << "rev in year 2: " << revYear[1][0] << " " << temp << "\n";`

Comment: @Bob__, sure, but this is kind of practice for my studies. Asking my lecturer, she answered that she is getting the expected result without giving any further information - was not really helpful.

Comment: @RichardCritten, sorry- a bit confusing. I just wanted to show in the upper part that I found a way to get the desired output.

The part at the bottom is the one I struggle with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, edit: My mistake. I didn´t want to print temp at the bottom again.

Comment: If your lecturer doesn't know that using an uninitialized variable results in undefined behaviour, they probably shouldn't be teaching C++

Comment: Found my mistake. Thank´s @Caleth. However your comment was not very constructive ;)

Comment: No, I really mean that. In other languages "Try it and see" is good advice, but it is *very dangerous* advice in C++.

Comment: Got it. However, my issue is solved. I just took a look at my "learning materials" and it says that arrays don´t need to be initialized since the number of rows and elements are defined. 

So, it was simply not clear to me that my mistake was very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first two `for` loops give me the desired output

Let's see why

```
// This variable is declared and contextually assigned a meaningful value: zero.
int temp = 0;

for (int j = 0; j<2;j++){
    for(int i = 0; i<12; i++){
        // Here it's updated, we want it to hold the sum. 
        temp += rev[j][i];
    }
    // Now it has reached its final value and can be shown.
    cout << "rev in year " << j+1 << ": " << temp << "\n";

    // Here it is RESETTED, so that it's ready for the next iteration.
    // It would be an error to start the sum from any value other than zero.
    temp = 0;
}
```

This snippet produces the correct result, but it's not quite idiomatic. You could rewrite it like the following:

```
for (int j = 0; j<2; j++)
{
    int temp = 0;  // <--- Initialize inside the loop, at the beginning.
    for(int i = 0; i<12; i++)
    {
        temp += rev[j][i];
    }
    std::cout << "rev in year " << j+1 << ": " << temp << "\n";
}
```

Even better, you could use one of the algorithms of the Standard Library, [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
for (size_t i{}; i < std::size(rev); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "revenue in year " << i + 1 << ": "
              << std::accumulate( std::begin(rev[i]), std::end(rev[i])
                                , 0 )  // <--- Initialization of the sum
              << '\n';
}
```

Now it should be clear why the second nested loop in the question's posted code fails.

```
// This variable is declared, but NOT initialized. Its elements have
// UNDETERMINED values, they could be equal to zero only by accident.
int revYear[2][1];

for (int j = 0; j<2;j++){
    for(int i = 0; i<12; i++){
        // While the code accumulates the values correctly, we don't know
        // the initial value, so the result will be likely wrong. 
        revYear[j][0] += rev[j][i];
    }
}
```

To fix it, we can properly initialize the array (it's still unclear to me why they want a 2D one, but that seems part of assignment).

```
int revYear[2][1]{};
```

Which IMHO is preferable to set the correct value at the beginning of the loop.

```
int revYear[2][1];   
for (int j = 0; j<2;j++)
{
    revYear[j][0] = 0;  // <---   
    // ...
    std::cout << "revenue in year " << j + 1 << ": " << revYear[j][0] << "\n";
}
```